# Assistance identifying an op-amp marked "H2P IFA"- includes photos

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification, surface-mount

I'm looking for help identifying this chip, which I believe is a dual op-amp (pin 4 is grounded, pin 8 is power). Package appears to be QFN, possibly with a pad (there are no vias under the chip). I suspect an op-amp because of the application (analogue sensor signal conditioning board) with several other op-amps.

If it is an op-amp, it will be a low-noise, low-offset, low-bias variety given the instrumentation application.

I've tried looking up the marking "H2P IFA" using a variety of reverse lookup tables without success (H2P returns some 5-pin devices).

I've said that the second line of marking is "IFA", but the "I" is curiously-wide. Under the scope it looks vaguely like a cartoon pine tree or a gummy bear (see images).
[image: Entire chip][image: Closeup of the "I"]

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: "pin 4 is grounded, pin 8" That's very common. You can't tell that something is an op amp just based on that.

Comment: @Lundin You are correct, but this is a signal conditioning board stuffed with op-amps, which added to my feeling this was another op-amp. Should have added this to my question.

Comment: @periblepsis Unlikely to be a fake chip (at least of that type) given the board manufacturer, but I do apologize for the photos. New scope camera and the only thing I could get working was the video, so the images are low-res screen captures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be Analog Devices [ADA4896 series](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ada4896-2_4897-1_4897-2.pdf). Single channel rail-to-rail OP. Marking H2P. Ground on pin 4, supply on pin 7 (pin 8 is a /Disable pin and could be tied to Vdd probably). And this might be what they call a "LFCSP-8" package aka MO-229, with a pad underneath the chip indeed (I'd probably call it "QFN" too).

Comment: You nailed it! The ADA4896-2 is on that datasheet and is a dual op-amp variant in an 8-pin package (without the disable function). Thank you!

Comment: For others out there thinking they might be looking at an Analog Devices part, you can search at https://www.analog.com/en/search.html. Entering H2P as a search term brought up the datasheet above.